# asp webform with no ties to a master page is pulling masterpage include files

Tags: asp.net, app-themes

In my asp.net web application I created a new web form (with NO master page).  The code to this page looks like this:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchPreload.aspx.cs" Inherits="CMS.ContractManagement.SearchPreload" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

however when I view the page, I have a background image, and when I do a view source on the page, I can see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><link href="../App_Themes/basic/ChangePasswordExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/CreateUserWizardExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/DataListExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/DetailsViewExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/ExamplesMaster.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/FormViewExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/GridViewExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/LoginExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/LoginStatusExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/MainMaster.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/MenuExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/PasswordRecoveryExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/SrcViewer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/TreeViewExample.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/basic/WhitePaper.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Where is this coming from and how can I remove it?  This page is only used to do some database manipulation and write out a javascript array to be fed into a jQuery function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your site set up to use the App_Themes in the web.config? If so, then it will automatically add any stylesheet to all of your .aspx pages.

Check your web.config for `<page theme="">`

Comment: Thank you for your help, you led me to the answer of setting EnableTheming="false" Theme="" and now it works. Thanks